# diff -s linux clarification requested

Tags: linux, diff

I have two identical files `a.txt` and `b.txt` both in `/files/minor` directory.
I need to compare whether there is a similar file to `a.txt` in the `/files/minor` directory. Not getting the `b.txt` result at all. Please help
from `/files/minor` issued the below:-

```
mylogin@myserver:minor$  diff -s a.txt /files/minor
```

Got result as : Files a.txt and /files/minor a.txt  are identical

Comment: Can you define "similar"?

Comment: I meant both a.txt and b.txt are one another same. and both are in directory /files/minor. so when issue diff -s a.txt /files/minor i would like to get in result both a.txt and b.txt . but getting only a.txt.